# filter file in .csv formar with pandas

Tags: pandas

I tried to filter my data  with pandas but I have not succeeded, I changed my data to a .csv file and did the following:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("test3.csv") 
print (type(data))
print(data)
```

By doing this I get my table:

```
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
2  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0
3  4.0  5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

Now I need that for the rows in which the columns meet a condition, python prints that row for example the rows for which all the columns are <4.0, the idea is that I have a condition for each column. I tried this but it does not work:

```
for item in data: 
    fil_C1=(data["C1"]) == 4.0
    print (fil_C1)
```

please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retain rows where columns value for C1 is less than 4, try the following:

```
less_than_4 = data[data['C1'] < 4]
print(less_than_4)
```

If you have multiple conditions say C1 less than 4 and C5 greater than 5 try this:

```
mul_conditions = data[(data['C1'] < 4) & (data['C5'] > 5)]
print(mul_conditions)
```

Let me know how it goes.